# Make cached jQuery objects available for multiple views in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone along with jQuery and requireJS.
I'd like to know what's a good way to make cached jQuery objects available for multiple views in Backbone. Let's say I have a *pageView*, *homeView*, *aboutView* and a *contactView*.

In all these views I'm manipulating the DOM and at the moment I need to create every time a new jQuery wrapper for the following DOM elements: *.side-left*, *.side-right*, *.page-left* and *.page-right*.

What's the best way to only wrap these elements once instead of always creating a new instance?

A first intention was to add all models to a collection and cache the DOM elements there. Unfortunately not all of my views have a model. How do I handle it then?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

The code below shows how I'm currently solving it for one view. But the others don't have access to this as they are not using the same model.

PageModel.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

    var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            leftSide: $('#splitlayout div.intro > div.side-left'),
            rightSide: $('#splitlayout div.intro > div.side-right'),
            pageLeft: $('#splitlayout div.page-left'),
            pageRight: $('#splitlayout div.page-right')
        }
    });

    return PageModel;

});
```

PageView.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'global',
    'models/video/VideoModel',
    'views/video/VideoView'
], function($, _, Backbone, Global, VideoModel, VideoView){

    var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("#splitlayout"),

        events: {
            'click .intro-content': 'resetLayout',
            'click .back': 'backToIntro'
        },

        render: function(){

            this.$el.addClass('reset-layout');
            this.model.get('pageLeft').on(Global.transEndEventName, this.onEndTransFn);
            this.model.get('pageRight').on(Global.transEndEventName, this.onEndTransFn);            

        },

        initialize: function() {

            _.bindAll(this);

            this.videoModel = new VideoModel();
            this.VideoView = new VideoView({model: this.videoModel});

            this.render();

        },

        onEndTransFn: function() {

            this.$el.addClass('reset-layout');
            $('html, body').scrollTop = 0;

        },

        backToIntro: function(ev) {

            ev.preventDefault();

            var dir = $(ev.currentTarget).hasClass('back-right') ? 'left' : 'right';

            this.$el.removeClass('open-' + dir);
            this.$el.addClass('close-' + dir);

        },

        resetLayout: function(ev) {

            var layoutClass = $(ev.currentTarget).parent().hasClass('side-left') ? 'open-left' : 'open-right';

            this.$el.addClass(layoutClass)
            this.$el.removeClass('close-right close-left reset-layout');

        }    

    });

    return PageView;

});
```

Comment: I use backbone with Chaplin framework, and it has a "reuse" method that helps you with that. Maybe you could read the source code to have an idea how to do it

Comment: I rather don't want to use another framework.. Are you aware of a built-in reuse method in underscore? I haven't found one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to sidestep your question a bit and say, just don't. IMO a view should be responsible for the element it is bound to and its children (be they more views or markup). If you want to communicate between the views you should be using an event bus (Below using the deafult `Backbone` but you can define your own). So for your case I would do the following,

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
   ...
   initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(Backbone, Global.transEndEventName, this.onEndTransFn);
      ...
    },
```

then whatever view is generating the event,

```
var VideoView = Backbone.View.extend({
   ...
   events: {
      'click div.page-left': 'eventFired',
   },
   eventFired : function(){
      Backbone.trigger(Global.transEndEventName);
   }
```

You don't really show the relationships of your views so this is just an example to extrapolate from.